# How to get -vf to ffmpeg from powershell commandline without parsing

Tags: powershell, parameters, ffmpeg

I made a powershell function to recode video with some extra parameters. It basically makes a get-childitem in the directory and feeds every occurrence it finds to a foreach loop. This worked well as long as I have default values inside my function which gets fed to the ffmpeg string in the loop in case I do not provide anything on the commandline (like number of passes, audio quality etc.). Now I wanted to integrate the option to use the -vf ffmpeg filter option. My problem there is, that I usualy dont need that, so there is no sane default option I could use, so I can not have something like -vf $filteroption in my command line. So I am trying to figure out how to get that "-vf" inside the variable without powershell or ffmpeg screwing me over, because atm I get either the error of a missing - in what ffmpeg sees (I guess powershell parses this away) and when I \ escape the - I see it now in the ffmpeg line, but ffmpeg does not recognize it as single parameter.

examples which work:

```
&$encoder -hide_banner -i $i -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 0 -crf $quality -tile-columns 6 -tile-rows 2 -threads 8 -speed 2 -frame-parallel 0 -row-mt 1 -c:a libopus -b:a $bitrate -af aformat=channel_layouts=$audio -c:s copy -auto-alt-ref 1 -lag-in-frames 25 -y $outfile;
```

here I provide $quality, $audio etc. with powershell parameters to the function like -quality 31 -audio stereo and it all works.

But now I need to get something like "`-vf scale=1920:-1`" or "" inside that line and that does not work with something like just this:

```
&$encoder -hide_banner -i $i -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 0 -crf $quality -tile-columns 6 -tile-rows 2 -threads 8 -speed 2 -frame-parallel 0 -row-mt 1 -c:a libopus -b:a $bitrate -af aformat=channel_layouts=$audio -c:s copy -auto-alt-ref 1 -lag-in-frames 25 -y $extra $outfile;
```

when I call the function with: "`RecodeVP9 -extra -vf scale=1920:-1`" powershell takes away the -, if I try it with escaping the - with - ffmpeg whines about it saying that "Unable to find a suitable output format for '-vf'". I also tried "" and "-" with similiar results. So it seems that either powershell screws me over or ffmpeg.

**So to sum it up:** 
*I need a way to get extra ffmpeg arguments WITH the parameter name itself from the powershell command line into my powershell function (like `-vf scale=1920:-1`).*

Comment: Suggestion: Define your variables as environment variables, then use the stop-parser operator and access them like you would from batch: `$Env:i = 'whatever'; & $encoder --% -hide_banner -i %i% ...`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 nice hint, do you know a documentation source for the batch type environment variable expanding?

Comment: @LotPings `cmd` is the fallback parser when you use the stop-parser operator.  `%varname%` is how you reference variables in `cmd` and all variables are environment variables there.